# Emacs - Using "Select All" in Function (how to find the function bound to a key)

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to figure out Elisp, and I've hit a roadblock.

I want a function that will Indent the entire file.  Right now, I'm selecting the whole file (<kbd>C-x h</kbd>) and then doing <kbd>M-x indent-region</kbd> (which does have a shortcut key).

I'd like to combine that in to a single keypress, but can't figure out how to do <kbd>C-x h</kbd> in a function.

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To find what Emacs will do when you invoke a certain key combination, prefix that with: <kbd>C-h k</kbd>.  In your case, you'd type:

```
C-h k C-x h
```

which yields

> C-x h runs the command
>   mark-whole-buffer, which is an
>   interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `simple.el'.
>
> It is bound to C-x h, 
>    .
>   (mark-whole-buffer)
>
> Put point at beginning and mark at end
>   of buffer. You probably should not use
>   this function in Lisp programs; it is
>   usually a mistake for a Lisp function
>   to use any subroutine that uses or
>   sets the mark.

*Note:* You can also use <kbd>C-h K</kbd> (note the <kbd>K</kbd> is capitalized), which will jump you to the documentation for the command.

Comment: Thank you sir, C-h k is what I could not find

Comment: and C-h c returns just the function, without any documentation, and without opening a help buffer. And, C-h C-h is nice for these situations.

Answer (score 12):

It is worth noting that you don't want to use the mark and point in non-interactive code; you want `(indent-region (point-min) (point-max))`, not `(save-excursion (mark-whole-buffer) (call-interactively indent-region))`, even though the effects are similar.

(Not to ruin your fun, but the whole sequence will look something like `(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-r") (lambda () (interactive) (indent-region (point-min) (point-max)))`.)

Comment: Why is your method preferred over marking the whole buffer / indent region?  I'm not sure what the difference is.